# In Windows 10, what is changing the filename extension of JPG files to JFIF?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, jpeg, content-type-association

In Windows 10, the value of Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\image/jpeg/Extension is changing from JPG to JFIF at frequent intervals

This value is changed roughly every 2 to 3 days, seemingly without any user action taken to change this value.

Every time this value is changed, programs no longer save JPG files with the extension .JPG; they are saved as .JFIF.

This breaks basically every script and program written in the last 30 years.

What is causing this change, and how can it be prevented?

Comment: Alright, it's the Google Chrome update process altering the value of this key every time it updates.

The rest of the question, "how can it be prevented," remains.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1271755/prevent-a-change-to-one-or-more-windows-10-registry-keys

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't do that so there are probably some malicious actors on your PC

To check you need to enable auditing and listen to registry modification [event 4657](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4657) to know who does that. See [How to monitor Registry changes](https://betanews.com/2015/11/18/how-to-monitor-registry-changes/) for more information